# What is the expected behavior of "href=logo.png"?

Tags: html, href

What is the expected behavior of "href=logo.png"?
There are two possible values for href:

1. An absolute URL
2. A relative path

But in this case there is no '/' before the "logo.png" so what is the path that the browser will look?

Comment: The same path as the html file is located.

Comment: What's your exact question about this? Why not simply craft an example and see what happens? Also, there are more conditions that might apply (like `<base href="http://www.example.com/">`)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the browser sees `href="logo.png"` as a relative path, so if you want that it works, you should have the html page in the same directory of `logo.png`.
An another way to use the relative path is `href="./logo.png"`. It's the same thing.